# Create a database entry for a value according to range

Tags: python, django

I'm working with Django/python and I need to enter a value in a database which has predefined ranges which correspond to the values.

Eg: If the entry I have to make has a value of 125. I need to retrieve the data for the range of 125-130. If the entry does not exist in the database then it should create a new entry in the database (suppose the range 130-135 does not exist when I have to work with a value of 132).

How should go about creating something like this? Is there a specific name for this kind of operation?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample model and a sample pseudo-code demonstrating the problem? Thanks.

Comment: It's the pseudo code I'm after. But I'll try and explain.
Suppose the database has the schema:
`range(int)|attribute(string)` with the values 
`120-125|foo`
`115-120|bar`
Pseudo Code:
`newData = 123`
`Enter into corresponding range //in this case 120-125`

I hope that helps